# Difference between Latent and Explicit Semantic Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, latent-semantic-indexing

I'm trying to analyse the paper ''[Computing Semantic Relatedness
using Wikipedia-based Explicit Semantic
Analysis](http://ijcai.org/papers07/Papers/IJCAI07-259.pdf)''.

One component of the system described therein that I'm currently grappling with is the difference between Latent and Explicit Semantic Analysis.

I've been writing up a document to encapsulate my understanding but it's somewhat, "cobbled together", from sources which I don't 100% understand, so I'd like to know if what I've come up with is accurate, here it is:

> When implementing a process like singular value decomposition (SVD) or Markov
>   chain Monte Carlo machines, a corpus of documents can be partitioned on the
>   basis of inherent characteristics and assigned to categories by applying different
>   weights to the features that constitute each singular data index. In this high dimensional
>   space it is often difficult to determine the combination of factors
>   leading to an outcome or result, the variables of interest are “hidden” or latent.
>   By defining a set of humanly intelligible categories, i.e. Wikipedia article
>   pages as a basis for comparison [Gabrilovich et al. 2007] have devised a system
>   whereby the criteria used to distinguish a datum are readily comprehensible,
>   from the text we note that “semantic analysis is explicit in the sense that we
>   manipulate manifest concepts grounded in human cognition, rather than ‘latent
>   concepts’ used by Latent Semantic Analysis”.
>   With that we have now established Explicit Semantic Analysis in opposition
>   to Latent Semantic Analysis.

is that accurate?

Info on this topic is somewhat sparse. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707624/explicit-semantic-analysis) ostensibly deals with a similar issue, though not really.